# Blocking in record linkage python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-matching, record-linkage

I have two `dataframes`, df1 and df2 that share multiple columns. Please see below for snippets of each dataframe.

```
df1

ps_number   ps_name cons_type   cons_number province    cons_type_num   district    ps_name_clean
0   1   Government Girls Primary School Comboo (Male)   NA  1   KPK NA-1    peshawar-i  government girls primary school comboo male
1   2   Government Girls Middle School Sarbaland Pura ...   NA  1   KPK NA-1    peshawar-i  government girls middle school sarbaland pura ...
2   3   Government Primary School No.1 Sarbaland Pura ...   NA  1   KPK NA-1    peshawar-i  government primary school no1 sarbaland pura m...
3   4   Government Girls Primary School Sarbaland Pura...   NA  1   KPK NA-1    peshawar-i  government girls primary school sarbaland pura...
4   5   Government Primary School Pahari Pura (Male) PS-1   NA  1   KPK NA-1    peshawar-i  government primary school pahari pura male ps 1
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
68346   304 Govt Girls Meddal School Musi Wali (Female) (P) NA  72  PUNJAB  NA-72   mianwali-ii govt girls meddal school musi wali female p
68347   305 Govt Boys High School Musi Wali Part-II (P) NA  72  PUNJAB  NA-72   mianwali-ii govt boys high school musi wali part ii p
68348   306 Govt GirlsMeddal School Tibba Mehr Ban Shah (P) NA  72  PUNJAB  NA-72   mianwali-ii govt girlsmeddal school tibba mehr ban shah p
68349   307 Govt Boys Pramiery School Murid Abbas Shah (P)  NA  72  PUNJAB  NA-72   mianwali-ii govt boys pramiery school murid abbas shah p
68350   308 Total votes recorded on postal ballot for the ...   NA  72  PUNJAB  NA-72   mianwali-ii total votes recorded on postal ballot for the ...
```

```
df2
    ps_name ps_number   province    cons_number type    lat lng description district    ps_name_stripped    ps_name_clean
0   Govt; High School (GHS) Arrandu 1   KPK 1   Combined    35.31008    71.55092    Polling Station: 1 - Govt; High School (GHS) A...   chitral Govt; High School (GHS) Arrandu govt high school ghs arrandu
1   Govt Girls Primary School (GGPS) Arrandu    2   KPK 1   Combined    35.31202    71.55158    Polling Station: 2 - Govt Girls Primary School...   chitral Govt Girls Primary School (GGPS) Arrandu    govt girls primary school ggps arrandu
2   Govt: Primary School Marakabat (PS No.1)    3   KPK 1   Combined    35.29211    71.56821    Polling Station: 3 - Govt: Primary School Mara...   chitral Govt: Primary School Marakabat (PS No.1)    govt primary school marakabat ps no1
3   Govt; Primary School Akroy  4   KPK 1   Combined    35.34268    71.61663    Polling Station: 4 - Govt; Primary School Akro...   chitral Govt; Primary School Akroy  govt primary school akroy
4   Govt Primary School Langoorbat  5   KPK 1   Combined    35.32656    71.59922    Polling Station: 5 - Govt Primary School Lango...   chitral Govt Primary School Langoorbat  govt primary school langoorbat
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
46814   Govt: Primary School Basool Ormara. (Comb)  358 BALOCHISTAN 272 Combined    25.43741    64.38839    Polling Station: 358 - Govt: Primary School Ba...   lasbela-cum-gwadar  Govt: Primary School Basool Ormara. (Comb)  govt primary school basool ormara comb
46815   Govt: Primary School Kahordan (Comb)    359 BALOCHISTAN 272 Combined    25.42091    64.41979    Polling Station: 359 - Govt: Primary School Ka...   lasbela-cum-gwadar  Govt: Primary School Kahordan (Comb)    govt primary school kahordan comb
46816   Govt: Primary School Thussak (Comb) 360 BALOCHISTAN 272 Combined    25.45371    64.48357    Polling Station: 360 - Govt: Primary School Th...   lasbela-cum-gwadar  Govt: Primary School Thussak (Comb) govt primary school thussak comb
46817   Govt:Boys Meddle School Chill Hud Ormara. (Comb)    364 BALOCHISTAN 272 Combined    25.24679    64.60839    Polling Station: 364 - Govt:Boys Meddle School...   lasbela-cum-gwadar  Govt:Boys Meddle School Chill Hud Ormara. (Comb)    govtboys meddle school chill hud ormara comb
46818   Govt: Boys Primary School Hud (Comb)    365 BALOCHISTAN 272 Combined    25.28109    64.64944    Polling Station: 365 - Govt: Boys Primary Sch...    lasbela-cum-gwadar  Govt: Boys Primary School Hud (Comb)    govt boys primary school hud comb
```

I am trying to string match the two `dataframes` on `ps_name_clean`, while blocking on `district`.

The problem is, the two `dataframes` don't share exactly the same districts. i.e. df1 has districts that df2 doesn't, and vice versa. In this case, my question is, what happens to those rows in df1 that have district that df2 doesn't have during string matching? Do they still get compared against all the rows in other districts?

I manually checked after running below to see what happens to those rows, and they do seem to get matched somehow with others that are not in the same district as them (inaccurate match, though). But I don't understand why, since I am blocking on districts, which, as far as I understand, means that only those in the same districts get compared against each other.

```
indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
indexer.block('district')
candidate_links = indexer.index(df1, df2)
c = recordlinkage.Compare()
c.string('ps_name_clean', 'ps_name_clean', method='damerau_levenshtein', threshold=0.75)
c_vectors = c.compute(candidate_links, df1, df2)
matches = c_vectors[c_vectors[0]==1.0]
matches.reset_index(inplace=True) 
matches.drop_duplicates(subset = ['level_0'], keep = 'last')
```

Can anyone explain what must be going on here?